# How to configure click event listener for combobox afterSubTpl content

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs5

Here I am using Ext JS 5.

My use case is to show sometext below the combobox input box. So, I used "afterSubTpl" config of combobox and showing the required text.
Now I have to raise an event when user clicked on the above specified text.

Comboboxes should not have click event in Ext JS. How to configure click event listener for this ?

```
// The data store containing the list of states
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
    data : [
        {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
        {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
        {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"}
    ]
});

// Create the combo box, attached to the states data store
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
    store: states,
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'abbr',
    afterSubTpl: '<div>My Custom Text</div>',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

[image]

Need to configure click event for the text shown in Red border.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a class to your div, then use `element` and `delegate` on the `click` event, like:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
        fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
        store: states,
        queryMode: 'local',
        displayField: 'name',
        valueField: 'abbr',
        afterSubTpl: '<div class="foo">My Custom Text</div>',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        listeners: {
            click: {
                element: 'el',
                delegate: '.foo',
                fn: function(){
                    console.log('click');
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/15r8

Answer (score 1):

In case of your code you can do something like this:

```
listeners: {
    afterrender: function(component) {
        var myDiv = component.getEl().down('div#myDiv');
        myDiv.on('click', function() {
            console.log('Clicked!');
        }); 
    }
}
```

[Working fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/15r7)